# Traveling with new passport to India, but forgot the old passport with the visa back home

Tags: visas, india

I live in Seattle and am a US citizen. I arrived in Hong Kong on 1/11. Yesterday, 1/16 I went to the airport to go to India, but when I got there to check in, the agent asked for my visa and I realized it was in my old passport in Seattle. Needless to say, I was unable to go on my flight. I still need to get to India.

What should I do? I'm going to the Indian consulate to see if they can help, but they don't open until tomorrow.

Comment: Get someone to overnight your old passport.

Comment: We looked into that, wouldn't make it in time. I need it by absolute latest Wednesday afternoon, called all the shipping services, they said it's possible but most likely Thursday.

Comment: Then you clearly didn't call the right services, there are many "get this document on the next flight" type of services. For eg https://www.upsexpresscritical.com/cfw/ http://www.fedex.com/us/government/us/options.html http://www.dhl.com/en/express/export_services/export_same_day.html In a pinch, call Delta Airlines and ask whether they'd be willing to carry it then get someone to the airport w/ the passport. There's a flight at 12:24PM every day arriving the next day. So it'll be there by Monday.

Comment: Thanks will try that. I called UPS, FedEx, and DHL. Will try Delta.

Comment: To clarify: you can't call the normal lines. UPS Express Critical: 1-800-714-8779 , FedEx:  1.800.247.4747 I edited my comment above with links.

Comment: Didn't work. Said that I needed an account with them, and because it involves TSA clearance it would take longer to set one up. Delta said to talk to their cargo department. I'll call once they open.

Comment: Ah i was wrong. Ups said that. FedEx said they could but their system is down for maintenance (great timing). I'll call back at 1am central and see what they can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34425/discussion-between-chx-and-vkapadia).

Comment: @chx In the end your comments were the right solution. Why not post them as a proper answer?

Comment: Yes, @chx please add your comment as an answer. Delta did end up delivering my passport in time. Saved my butt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a situation like this, your best bet is airlines which also provide cargo services -- most often you can get the package on the next flight out. You need to look up which airlines fly between the given airports for fastest service as you do not want layovers, in this case, Delta has a SEA-HKG flight (Singapore Airlines Cargo also flies this route as a backup option, it's worth a call to check but it's likely an ordinary airline will be quicker). If someone does a handover at the airport and you pick it up at the other airport then it'll be as fast as possible and the cost won't be exorbitant since it's very small. You can send (it happened!) multi ton power plant turbine shafts this way -- now *that* will be jaw dropping expensive but it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, Delta Cargo worked for me! It was a bit pricey,  bt nothing too bad. Took multiple trips to Hong Kongs

Comment: (continued from last line) Cargo Terminal, but was finally able to get my passport.